# Fermat's little theorem $a^y \pmod{p}$ when $y<p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have a problem where I need to guess $425^{17} \pmod{541}$

$p=541$ is prime so, applying Fermat's little Theorem $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ we got

$425^{540} \equiv 1 \pmod{541}$

But how should I continue?

I am trying $\frac{17}{540}= 0*540 + 17$ but nothing to do with this...

Comment: You don't have to "guess" anything. Just type `pow(425,17,541)` in a Python prompt and see the answer is $282$.

Comment: I know the result, but I want to achieve it by using FLT

Comment: FLT really doesn't help much here. The best course of action is repeated squaring, to get from $a$ to $a^2$ to $a^4$ to $a^8$ to $a^{16}$, all mod $p$ (so the numbers stay small), followed by $a^{16}\cdot a$ to get $a^{17}$.

Comment: FLT is useless here.

Comment: FLT would be handy if the exponent would be $> 540 = p-1$, to reduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on doing it by hand, use repeated squaring (via a calculator for squaring and "remaindering" by $541$):

- $425^2 $ has remainder $472$ on division by $541$.
- So $425^4 = 272^2 \pmod{541}$ and that is again (by a standard calculator) equal to $433$.
- Hence $425^8 = 433^2 \pmod{541}$ which equals $303$.
- Hence $425^{16} = 303^2 \pmod{541}$, and this is $380$.
- So finally $425^{17}= 425 \cdot 380 \pmod{541} = 282$.

Which Python will immediately compute (essentially via this same algorithm ) by `pow(425,17,451)`, which is a bit easier.